# Calling setHasOptionsMenu(true) from a fragment results in multiple calls to onCreateOptionsMenu in Activity

Tags: android, view, android-activity, android-viewpager, fragment

I have a simple `Activity` that contains a `ViewPager`. I'm attempting to add some menu items to the menu from one of my `Fragment`s, however I'm getting some strange behavior. Calling: `setHasOptionsMenu(true);` from my fragment results in the enclosing Activity's `onCreateOptionsMenu()` method to be called every time I change fragments in the `ViewPager`. Is this normal?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It's absolutely "normal."  It may not fit with your particular use case, but it's definitely intended behavior.

Take a look at the source for android.support.v4.app.Fragment.setHasOptionsMenu():

```
public void setHasOptionsMenu(boolean hasMenu) {
    if (mHasMenu != hasMenu) {
        mHasMenu = hasMenu;
        if (isAdded() && !isHidden()) {
            mActivity.supportInvalidateOptionsMenu();
        }
    }
}
```

You can see it calls `supportInvalidateOptionsMenu()` on it's activity, which ultimately leads to `onCreateOptionsMenu()` being called on the activity and all of it's fragments.  It's how the framework manages updating the options menu when a fragment is added/removed from an activity's fragment manager.

Comment: Thanks, it does make life difficult for me at the moment but at least I know it is intended behavior.