# What is the flow like for options menu when we add them in fragment and the main activity?

Tags: android

I am learning android and I am a bit unsure about how menu options work.Here is the set up I have,

> I have a main activity which has a fragment inside it. Main activity's  onCreateOptionsMenu looks like this

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    return true;
}
```

This menu_main.xml just has settings button. I was supposed to add a refresh button in the fragment so I created a new menu xml and added this code in the fragment class

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    inflater.inflate(R.menu.tempfragment, menu);
}
```

When I ran the app and did the longpress, I saw both refresh and setting button.

My question is that when we have a menu options for main activity and for a its associated fragment, what is the flow like? Does it combine both of the menus? I can see it is combining but I am bit unsure regarding how it is getting handled internally? Can somebody explain this to me?

Edit
Here is menu file for the fragment

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto" >

<item android:id="@+id/action_refresh" android:title="action_refresh"
    app:showAsAction="never"
    />
</menu>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a `MainActivity` that inflates an options menu, `menu_main.xml`, then that options menu will always be present on any fragment that the `MainActivity` creates.

Within each fragment code, you can create options menus for that specific fragment. Say you inflate `menu_friends.xml` in `FriendsFragment`. When an instance of `FriendsFragment` is created by `MainActivity`, both `menu_main.xml` **and** `menu_friends.xml` will be shown. You can repeat this for all fragments.

Edit: @Kartheek is incorrect with his answer regarding calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` in a fragment cancelling out the activity's menu. All that statement does is allow a menu to be created by that fragment. **Both** menus will be included. See here:
[Calling setHasOptionsMenu(true) from a fragment results in multiple calls to onCreateOptionsMenu in Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22151458/calling-sethasoptionsmenutrue-from-a-fragment-results-in-multiple-calls-to-onc)

Comment: So, If I understand correctly, as long as main activity is open, it's menu options will be visible along the menu option of its fragments, however we open another activity from main_activity, then option menu of the other activity will replace the main activity's option menu. Is that correct?:

Answer (score 1):

> when we have a menu options for main activity and for a its associated
>   fragment ?

If your fragment has called the `setHasOptionsMenu` to `true` then `onCreateOptionsMenu` will be called in your fragment and also in your activity.It actually combines the menu items of the `Activity` and the `Fragment`.

> Does it combine both of the menus?

Yes. It combines both of them it displays them in a whole.

> Can somebody explain this to me?

You can declare items for the options menu from either your `Activity` subclass or a `Fragment` subclass. If both your activity and fragment(s) declare items for the options menu, they are combined in the UI. The activity's items appear first, followed by those of each fragment in the order in which each fragment is added to the activity. If necessary, you can re-order the menu items with the `android:orderInCategory` attribute in each `<item>` you need to move.

If your activity includes fragments, the system first calls `onOptionsItemSelected()` for the activity then for each fragment (in the order each fragment was added) until one returns true or all fragments have been called.

Comment: But for me it is showing both in my final UI, also McGuile answer below also says it will show options menu for both

Comment: Every menu.xml has settings button by default. i guess you have'nt removed it.

Comment: I don't think that is the case. I have updated the question with my menu.xml class for the fragment. As you can see it has just one item.

Comment: Updated my answer have a look. Corrected my mistake @Dude

Answer (score 1):

Dont forgent thet the main activity conties the fragment, and the actionbar is in the activity, so if you change the fragment its not like you change the activity...
Becuse of it the action bar not change, its just combiens between the action bar thet you have already in the activity, and the actionbar thet you have in the fragment.

Hope its help you :)